# ActionListen didn't fire on JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jmenu

I am fairly new java programming. I created a `JMenu` and add the `actionlisten`, but it didn't fire. The `JPanel`, `jpCommentMainPane`, is added to `JFrame`. Also the `JFrame` has its own menu bar and `actionlistener`. Would someone tell me how to make it work.  Thanks in advance.

There is my code to add the `JMenu` into the `JPanel`:

```
jpCommentMainPane=new JPanel();         
jpCommentMainPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
JPanel totalCommentPane=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
JPanel jpFindPane=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));      
totalCommentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(rightPaneWidth,20));        
jpFindPane.add(sortMenu());  //add menubar
JPanel topPane=new JPanel();
topPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
topPane.add(jpFindPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
jpCommentMainPane.add(topPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

There is the method to return the JMenuBar

```
//Create sort menu bar
private JMenuBar sortMenu(){

    JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu=new JMenu("Sort");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem menuItemType=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Type");
    menu.add(menuItemType);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem menuItemPage=new  JRadioButtonMenuItem("Page");
    menu.add(menuItemPage);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem menuItemAuthor=new  JRadioButtonMenuItem("Author");
    menu.add(menuItemAuthor);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem menuItemDate=new  JRadioButtonMenuItem("Date");
    menu.add(menuItemDate);
    menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){            
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
             Utility.DisplayErrorMsg(pageErrorPrefix+ "line 145");
            String command=e.getActionCommand().trim().toUpperCase();
            if (command.equals(SortItem.TYPE)){
                pageSortBy=SortItem.TYPE;
            }else if (command.equals(SortItem.PAGE)){
                pageSortBy=SortItem.PAGE;
            }else if(command.equals(SortItem.TYPE)){
                pageSortBy=SortItem.TYPE;
            }else if(command.equals(SortItem.CREATOR)){
                pageSortBy=SortItem.CREATOR;
            }else if (command.equals(SortItem.DATE)){
                pageSortBy=SortItem.DATE;
            }

            getListCommentPane();

        }

    }

            );
    menuBar.add(menu);
    return menuBar;


}
```

Comment: I think that you need to add ActionListeners to JMenuItems, not to JMenus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMenus need MenuListeners not ActionListeners to handle events. JMenuItems will use ActionListeners , however I'm not sure about JRadioButtonMenuItems.

One thing to try would be using inner classes for each JRadioButtonMenuItem.

For example, for the menuItemType

```
public class menuItemTypeListener implements ActionListener{
     public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         //Do Something here
     }
}

menuItemType.addActionListener(new menuItemTypeListener());
```

Comment: JRadioButtonMenuItem use ActionPerformed and ItemListener. Thanks for your suggestion. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm sure now. You can add an ActionListener to a JMenu, but unlike a JMenuItem, it has no effect. Instead if the JMenu object needs a listener, you should add a MenuListener to your JMenu.

Comment: I added the menuListener to JMenu. also add the ActionListener to JMenuItem. However it didn't fire if I click the JMenuItem.